# rails 4 params on hash and save it into db with virtual attributes

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, save, parameters

first, sorry for my bad english..

i got some problem here

i have the output data from view form

```
{
code: 'code supplier',
name: 'name supplier',
address: 'address supplier', 
phone_number: 'phone number supplier',
fax: 'fax supplier',
contact_persons: [
  {name: 'contact person 1', value_number: '123456', value_type: 'mobile phone'},
  {name: 'contact person 2', value_number: '123456', value_type: 'mobile phone'},
  {name: 'contact person 3', value_number: '123456', value_type: 'email'},
  {name: 'contact person 4', value_number: '123456', value_type: 'bb'}
  ]
bank_accounts: {
  name: 'hendrik',
  account_number: '1234578',
  bank_name: 'bca',
  branch_name: 'pasirkaliki'
  }
}
```

and I want to save it all into associated tables using virtual attributes, I tried some code

```
#VIRTUAL ATTRIBUTES
attr_accessor :address, :phone_number, :fax, :contact_person, :bank_account,    :value_number, :value_type, :bank_id, :account_name

# CALLBACKS
before_save :set_extra_attributes

def self.virtual_attributes
  [:address, :phone_number, :fax, :bank_account, :contact_person, :value_number, :value_type, :bank_id, :account_name]
end

def set_extra_attributes
  self.addresses = [Address.new(address: self.address)] if self.address.present?
  self.phone_numbers = [PhoneNumber.new(number: self.phone_number, phone_type: 'phone')] if self.phone_number.present?
  self.phone_numbers = [PhoneNumber.new(number: self.fax, phone_type: 'fax')] if self.fax.present?
  self.bank_accounts = [BankAccount.new(account_number: self.bank_account, holding_company_id: '1', bank_id: self.bank_id.to_i, name: self.account_name)] if self.bank_account.present?

  contact = [name: self.contact_person, value_type: self.value_type, value_number: self.value_number]

  contact.each do |u|
  ContactPerson.new(name: u[:name], value_type: u[:value_type], value_number: u[:value_number])
  end
end
```

I use Postgre,
I am totally not sure of my code above because it set every column (e.g self.value_type) into virtual attributes and its not efficient, any way to set just bank_account and contact_person only as virtual attributes and other column like (e.g self.value_type) just set in the hash like contact_person[:value_type], i've tried this one but still faced some problem, how to do that??
or u guys have another good way to solved that,, i really appreciate that, thank's

Comment: So "virtual attributes" seem to be [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) for Rails.

Comment: have you solution for that, i totally no idea,,